# Interpreting resolution rule of inference

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I know that the the resolution rule of inference states that

> $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r) \to (p \lor q)$

Based on this, my textbook says that below statement is true:

> $(p \vee q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$ is satisfiable.

However if we look at the resolution rule, it says LHS implies RHS. Thus even if LHS is false, RHS can be true. Doesn't that mean, RHS can be satisfied even if LHS is unsatisfiable and thus not only when LHS is satisfiable?

Comment: The statement is quite "misleading" ... $p \lor q$ is not a contradiction; thus it is *satisfiable*, and the same for the second formula.

Comment: so do you mean to say that they are independently satisfiable and is it like there is nothing like "$x$ is satisfiable if (and only if) $y$ is satisfiable". Because now I feel I dont understand what does it mean by $x$ is satisfiable if (and only if) $y$ is satisfiable. Does it mean $y \to x$?

Comment: As per @Arthur's answer, they are not equivalent; thus the rule means that if the LHS is satisfiable by some truth assignment $v$, then the same $v$ satisfy also the RHS. But the other "direction" is not true. If we do not ask for satisfiability by the same truth assignment, then the two formulae are satisfiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the claim is just that they're both satisfiable, not necessarily in the very same models (assignments of truth values ot variables). In particular, there's no claim that the converse is a valid inference rule -- it isn't, as the converse of the implication is not valid.

Because the given formula
$$
\vdash (p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r) \to (p \lor q)\tag{1}
$$
is valid (a tautology, provable), certainly it's clear that if $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$ is satisfiable then so is $(p \lor q)$. In fact, any assignment of truth values to propositional variables that satisfies the former, also satisfies the latter, because it has to assign *true* to at least one of $p, q$.

Now suppose $(p \lor q)$ is satisfiable. Then under some assignment $v$ of truth values to variables, $v(p) = 1$ or $v(q) = 1 = true$ — without loss of generality, say $v(p) = 1$. Let $v'$ agree with $v$ on all variables except possibly $r$, where $v'(r) = 0 = false$. Then 
$$
v'((p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)) = 1,
$$
so $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$ is satisfiable too.

Comment: **(1)** I feel it hard to understand what does it mean $x$ is satisfiable if and only $y$ is satisfiable. Does that mean $y \to x$? **(2)** Does "$(p \vee q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$ is satisfiable" means  the converse, i.e. $(p \lor q) \to (p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$? **(3)** and very sorry I didnt get the explanation with $v()$, may be a truth table might help me, if thats easy to form, may be with wolframalpha

Comment: (1) No, it does NOT mean that. It means (there's some assignment of values to variables in $x$ making $x$ true) if and only if (there's some assignment of values to variables in $y$ making $y$ true). (2) No, $(p\lor q)\to (p\lor r)\land(q\lor \neg r)$ is not provable, and is not valid. (3) $v$ IS the truth table. $v(p) = true, v(q) = false, v(r) = false$ satisfies $(p\lor r)\land(q\lor \neg r)$

Comment: Did my last comment clarify?

Comment: Very sorry for late response. That was actually easy, but your sentence formation in last paragraph of answer confused me, especially because I didn't came across $v()$ stuff earlier. But now it looks normal that I get it, only if following summary I get is correct: "*the converse $(p\vee q)\to (p\vee r)\wedge(q\vee \lnot r)$ is not valid/tautology, but its satisfiable for values $p=1, q=1, r=0$*". Thats it there right?...And lastly about your response to my question **(1)** Just curious if you can give me example of: "$x$ is satisifiable if and only if $y$ is satisifiable, but $y \not \to x$"

Comment: I just cleaned up the language a bit, hopefully it's an improvement. As for your last question asking for an example of $x$ satisfiable iff $y$ satisfiable, but $x\leftrightarrow y$ not valid (= provable), now we know one: $x := (p\lor q)$, $y := (p\lor r)\land(q\lor \neg r)$.

Comment: I understood this, but I think we discussed whether the converse of implication is true & how for particular $v()$ if $p \lor q$ is satisfiable, $(p \lor r)\land(q \lor \lnot r)$ is also satisfiable, but we didnt talk about "$(p∨q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is satisfiable." I too got dragged away from the original question. Again, I understand that satisfiability does not mean for same set of values of a variables (which is the case with implication). Can we generalize this for every $p\to q$: "*$q$ is satisifiable if and only if $p$ is satisifiable*"...

Comment: ...How can we prove this statement mathematically or with some argument (that is:"$p\vee q\$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is satisifiable")? I know this statement might be sort of obvious, but still something more formal / rigid / verbose argument may bring some clarity. Or is it just another interpretation of the implication?

Comment: Now I'm confused. Haven't we proved this statement already? Isn't that the question at the top?

Comment: As I said, I think we discussed whether the converse of implication is true & how, for particular $v()$, if $p∨q$ is satisfiable, $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is also satisfiable, but we didnt talk about this: "$(p∨q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is satisfiable." At the start of your answer you did pointed out that this statement talks about satisfiability but not necessarily in very same models, but did not elaborate on statement (may be there is nothing to elaborate about it, and I am just unnecessarily asking for elaboration, it might be another interpretation of implication, is it?)...

Comment: ...I dont know if I am stupid, or that is too obvious to miss. But please, one last time, can you just copy paste in comments, the sentence in your answer that says more about "$(p∨q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is satisfiable."

Comment: To clear up things further, I want to know if this: "$(p∨q)$ is satisfiable if and only if $(p∨r)∧(q∨¬r)$ is satisfiable." is true. If yes is it just another interpretation of implication & does not require explicit proof, or can it be proved with some formal proof/statement? I understand it does not talk about satisfiability in same model $v()$ which is what you explained in answer. And sorry if I ran insane with this. I guess I will end up cramming this up.

Comment: OK, $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r) \to (p \lor q)$ is a theorem/valid, so clearly if $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$ is satisfiable then so is $(p \lor q)$, in the same model, with the same values of $p,q$. The opposite direction of the "iff" is addressed by the last paragraph of my answer: if $(p \lor q)$ is satisfiable then so is $(p \lor r)\wedge (q \lor \lnot r)$.

Answer (score 0):

The second statement (with the "if and only if") is false (consider what would happen if we had $p$ and $r$ true and $q$ false). The two formulae are not equivalent.